# Using handleOpenURL with Custom URL scheme in Cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm developing an app and have almost everything figured out, except for the custom URL scheme plugin(https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme). I've successfully installed the plugin and set up a custom URL scheme of signsrestaurantandbar. So when I use signsrestaurantandbar://, my application opens. The problem I'm facing is handling the URL. In the readme, it says I can use function handleOpenURL(URL) for this, but I'm still having issues trying to load a particular page within the app.

Here's what I tried:

```
function handleOpenURL(url) {
      var strValue = url;
      strValue = strValue.replace('signsrestaurantandbar://','');
      window.location.href = strValue + ".html";
  }
```

I put this in my index.html page... though it should open page.html on loading signsrestaurantandbar://page, it doesn't do it properly. In my chrome console, it says it loaded the page, but it appears blank without any error and this happens only once. When I try to load signsrestaurantandbar://page the second time, it just loads the app.

I would appreciate any hints on how to approach loading particular pages using the custom URL scheme.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to make sure you list your "custom" URL in your `CSP`.

Added 2016-02-11: **NOTE: YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**

It would look something like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src * signsrestaurantandbar:; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

Usually the wildcard setting (`*`) can handle most applications, but not your "custom" protocol.
**NOTE:** Wildcard setting have the potential of keep your app out of the "app stores".

You may also need to add to your `config.xml`

```
<allow-intent href="signsrestaurantandbar:" />
```

This *whitelist* worksheet should help.
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

You should also read the [*whitelist* matrix](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-matrix.md), especially the sectionon `<allow-intent (...) />` - Best of Luck

Comment: Would there be any other reason handleOpenURL() isn't invoked? I've tried the above approach with the `<allow-intent>` and the CSP together but still can't get the function to get called.

Comment: Fixed my issue. For some reason the handleOpenURL() function only works when I have it in `<script>` tag within the HTML body.

Comment: @johnborges the above settings will make your app insecure. In addition, your app maybe reject by the "app stores". If you keep you Javascript and CSS in a separate file, you don't need to use the CSP; this will also help to secure your App.

Comment: @johnborges : Have you tried using the same with ionic project and got it working? In Ionic + Angular, As the handleopenURL needs to be in the controllers/app.js I am not able to use it. But when its places outside contoller and included in the body its working! **Any other way to get it working the ionic + angular way?**

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 thanks for the tip. Since my previous posting I've moved away from this plugin and have been using Universal Links instead.  https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin

Comment: @DileepMettu This is where knowing a bit more about javascript helps. I used the "EventEmitter.js" library to dispatch an event and listened to the event on the angular.run (angular 1) function.

Answer (score 11):

Add global handleOpenURL function using this code:

```
window.handleOpenURL = function(url) {
  console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
  // do stuff, for example
  // document.getElementById("url").value = url;
  console.log(url);
};
```

See [Cordova Custom URL Scheme Handling](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Custom%20URL%20Scheme%20Handling.md).

Note that if you use `alert` in this function your app would hang:

> You cannot launch any interactive features like alerts in the handleOpenURL code, if you do, your app will hang. Similarly, you should not call any Cordova APIs in there, unless you wrap it first in a setTimeout call, with a timeout value of zero.

The benefit of this method is you don't need to change Content Security Policy using `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag.

Comment: Where exactly do I add your code? I tried `document.addEventListener('deviceready',function (){...` but did not work.

Comment: @sooon Yes, that's where I place it, in `deviceready` event handler. How do you test that your `handleOpenURL` has been invoked? I noticed that Chrome Developer tools doesn't log reliably for me.

Comment: I put a `<div>urlscheme</div>` at `index.html` and using `jQuery` to replace the text `urlscheme` with the url, just to see if it works. but so far no result.

Comment: @PavelChuchuva: 2017 , not working. you must have missed somthign in the instruction which is confusing us. please update.

Comment: I was struggling with this same issue - even after making the above modifications, the handleOpenURL function would not be called.  The custom URL scheme would open my app, but the function would not be called.  

After I added <script src="cordova.js"></script> to the <head> of my index.html file, it works!